# python 3.x SOAP library for writing serverless webservice on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, soap, aws-lambda, serverless

I need to convert some legacy Java code that implements a SOAP server - I need to convert it from java to python 3.x and I need to deploy the SOAP webservices on AWS Lambda. There is plenty of documentation on how to create REST web services on AWS Lambda in python, but I'm finding it really hard to find any information on writing a SOAP service. There are some client libraries for python SOAP, but I can't seem to find any server-side libraries or examples of how one would do this on AWS Lambda. I found zeep, which is meant to be a client library, and pysimplesoap, but in neither case is it clear how to use these on AWS Lambda. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: So I discovered that SOAP  over HTTP is simply a call to HTTP POST which passes the SOAP request message as the HTTP body. (Of course there are headers in the HTTP request too that indicate that the body is a soap/xml message). So, to deploy to AWS Lambda, I basically need to deploy an HTTP PSOT webservice, which is easy enough using Zappa and Flask (or Django). The only tricky part is inside the post() function. Inside that function I would have to:

1. Get the request.body (SOAP/XML)
2. Use some python library to extract the items of interest from the SOAP message, perhaps parsing the entire message using a python XML parser
3. Execute the business logic code that creates a result, say a dictionary
4. Use some python library to convert that result dictionary to a SOAP response and let AWS Lambda send that SOAP response back

It is parts 2 and 4 that I am not quite sure how to do. I can use xml.etree.ElementTree to parse the XML, but I suspect there might be a better/faster/simpler way. For the output, is there a way I can use something like zeep to take a dictionary of inputs and create a SOAP response message? The zeep library is meant to read the WSDL document and create request SOAP messages, not response SOAP messages, so I'm not exactly sure how to create a SOAP response message using zeep. Has anyone else done this or know of a better way to do it?

Comment: I use `zeep` for SOAP client on Lambda. Works like charm with no special blackmagic. Just install it to your Lambda package. Server-side should theoretically work very similar. As for providing an endpoint, have a more detailed look at the settings of API Gateway. You can set it up to the Lambda_Proxy mode and handle all the logic in the code of your function.

Comment: Yes I suspected zeep would be useful but that is a client library. Can it be used on the server to parse the incoming SOAP request data? Can it be used to take a dictionary of results and create a SOAP response? If so, how?

Comment: You can definitely use `zeep` to serialize/deserialize requests on the interfaces of your Lambda SOAP application. But the actual logic you will most likely have to implement yourself anyway.